# How I can implement the same divider

Tags: android, android-preferences

How I can implement same divider as in Android system preferences?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This is not a divider, it is a `CardView `, check the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)

Comment: @diogojme thanks. But how implement the cards in preferences.xml/PreferenceFragment?